# how to print value obtained in foreach loop outside the loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach, datatable

I have found the value of `denom` and `numer` inside `foreach` loop and I want to use them to find the `average = numer/denom`. But it is showing an error that:

> The name 'numer' does not exist in the current context.

And

> The name 'denom' does not exist in the current context.

Please have a look at the code and suggest a fix.

```
foreach (DataRow rw in dataTablebuy.Rows)
{
     int denom = 0;
     denom = denom + int.Parse(rw["Quantity"].ToString());
     int numer = 0;
     numer = numer + (int.Parse(rw["Quantity"].ToString()) * int.Parse(rw["price"].ToString()));

}
float avg = numer / denom;
Response.Write(String.Format("Element {0}", avg));
```

Comment: The question is answered, but notice the loop itself is also wrong: the `denom` and `number` values will be not summarized, the previous value will be always lost because of 'int xxx = 0' in each iteration. Anyway you should declarate these variables outside of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the variables outside the loop. Else it can't be used outside the loop (scope).
I also changed something in your code. You used `denom = denom + ...`, check how I did it. It works exactly the same.

```
int denom = 0;
int numer = 0;
foreach (DataRow rw in dataTablebuy.Rows)
{
     denom += int.Parse(rw["Quantity"].ToString());
     numer += (int.Parse(rw["Quantity"].ToString()) * int.Parse(rw["price"].ToString()));
}
float avg = numer / denom;
Response.Write(String.Format("Element {0}", avg));
```

Comment: avg is a floating point value.. but I am getting integer , do u know how to print the floating point value??

Comment: @Darkknight `float avg = (float)numer / denom;` this fixes it

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have anything else to ask, just post the question. Make sure you've tried enough to fix it though, don't just ask a question without trying to fix it yourself.

Comment: Sure Kal, I will keep that in ma mind.. thank u for ur suggestion and help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the variables outside the loop then they need to be declared outside the loop.